# How to Concatenate local file path with pfx file path in powershell

Tags: powershell

I have created one powershell script which will Enable SSL for local website which will run as docker container on Linux OS. I have created pfx file for that.
But now I want to concatenate my local dev file path with pfx file path in powershell script. Can someone help me in this?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Powershell offers `Join-Path` to do this. As an example, let's append a subdirectory of the current directory and get that path:

```
$current = (Get-Location).Path
$sub = "mychilddirectory"
Join-Path $current $sub
```

This will return `$current` and `$sub` concatenated with the correct path separators for your OS.